# ¿Por qué los botones de datatable con jQuery y Ajax me regresa undefined solo la segunda vez?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mvc

Estoy agregando en mi `function rellenar()` botones a un *datatable* para incrementar y disminuir un valor específico de la fila. Llamo al método del botón `Agregar()` que espera un clic. En este método uso Ajax nuevamente para traer la nueva información de la tabla desde un controlador.

Esto funciona solo la primera vez, me regresa mi objeto y puedo agregarlo llamando al primer método `rellenar()`. Pero la segunda vez, al llamar al método del botón, el valor de la fila me regresa `undefined`

Primero llamo a este método que inicializa *listas* y llama a mi método `rellenar()`:

```js
$("#Articulo").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  articular();
});

var articular = function () {
  $listaIdVenta = $("#IdVentas");
  $.ajax({
    url: "/veVentas/GetDatosVenta",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      IdRegistro: $("#IdRegistro").val(),
      IdSucursal: $("#IdSucursal").val(),
      IdUsuario: $("#IdUsuario").val(),
      FechaVenta: $("#FechaVenta").val(),
      Subtotal: $("#Subtotal").val(),
      IEPS: $("#IEPS").val(),
      IVA: $("#IVA").val(),
      Total: $("#Total").val(),
      Folio: $("#Folio").val(),
      Productos: $("#Productos").val(),
      Estatus: $("#Estatus").val(),
      Tipo: $("#Tipo").val(),
      TipoPago: $("#TipoPago").val(),
      IdRegistroDetalle: $("#IdRegistroDetalle").val(),
      IdVentasDetalle: $("#IdVentasDetalle").val(),
      IdProductoDetalle: $("#IdProductoDetalle").val(),
      PrecioUniDetalle: $("#PrecioUniDetalle").val(),
      IEPSUniDetalle: $("#IEPSUniDetalle").val(),
      IVAUniDetalle: $("#IVAUniDetalle").val(),
      CantidadDetalle: $("#CantidadDetalle").val(),
      EstatusDetalle: $("#EstatusDetalle").val(),
      DescuentoDetalle: $("#DescuentoDetalle").val(),
    },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
      //console.log(result);
      let vali = result;

      if (result[0] == 1) {
        $(".toast").addClass("Rechazado");
        $(".toast").html(result[1]);
      } else {
        $(".toast").addClass("Aceptado");
        $("#Productos").val(result["productos"]);
        $(".toast").html(result["item1"]["value"][1]);

        //console.log(result['item2']['value'][0]['idVentas']);
        //console.log(result);
        var precio;

        $("#ventaid").text(
          "Agregar Productos " + result["item2"]["value"][0]["idVentas"]
        );

        rellenar(result["item2"]["value"]);
      }
      $(".toast").toast("show");
    },
    error: function () {
      $(".toast").toast("show");
    },
  });
};
```

Luego en `rellenar()`, recibo el objeto y hasta aquí todo bien. Agrego los botones en *defaultcontent* al final, llamo al método del primer botón y le envío `tbody` y la tabla:

```js
function rellenar(datos) {
  CalcularTotal(datos);
  var table = $("#dataTable").DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    data: datos,
    columns: [
      //{ "data": "idRegistro" },
      //{ "data": "idVentas" },
      //{ "data": "idProducto" },
      { data: "producto" },
      { data: "precioUni" },
      { data: "iepsUni" },
      { data: "ivaUni" },
      { data: "cantidad" },
      { data: "estatus" },
      { data: "descuento" },
      {
        defaultContent:
          "<button type='button'id='sumar' class='plus btn btn-success'>+</button><button type='button' class='minus btn btn-warning'>-</button><button type='button' class='delete btn btn-danger'>X</button>",
      },
      //asp - action='Sumar'  asp - route - id='@item.IdProducto'
      //{ "defaultContent": "<button asp-action='EditTemporal' asp-route-id='@item.IdProducto' class='dropdown-item'>+</button><button asp-action='EditTemporal' asp-route-id='@item.IdProducto' class='dropdown-item' > -</button ><button asp-action='EliminarTempDetalle' asp-route-id='@item.IdProducto' class='dropdown-item'>Eliminar</button>"}
    ],

    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: "excel",
        text: "<i ></i>",
        className: "btn btn-success btn-sm icon-excel3",
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "th:not(:last-child)",
        },
      },
      {
        extend: "pdf",
        text: "<span ></span>",
        className: "btn btn-danger btn-sm icon-pdf3",
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "th:not(:last-child)",
        },
      },
    ],
    language: {
      lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ por página",
      zeroRecords: "Ninguna coincidencia",
      info: "Página  _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
      infoEmpty: "No hay registros disponibles",
      infoFiltered: "(_MAX_ registros)",
      sSearch: "Buscar",
      oPaginate: {
        sFirst: "Primero",
        sPrevious: "Anterior",
        sNext: "Siguiente",
        sLast: "Último",
      },
    },
  });

  Agregar("#dataTable tbody", table);
}
```

Todo esto llega a este método, donde con Ajax mando mi `id` para saber cuál incrementar y me regresa la lista entera:

```js
var Agregar = function (tbody, table) {
  $(tbody).on("click", "button.plus", function () {
    var datos = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
    console.log("agregar");
    console.log(datos);
    //$('#IdProductoDetalle').val(datos['idProducto']);

    //$('#CantidadDetalle').val(1);
    //articular();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/veVentas/Sumar",
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        idProducto: datos["idProducto"],
      },
      traditional: true,
      success: function (result) {
        console.log("result");
        console.log(result);
        console.log("result 0");
        console.log(result[0]);

        rellenar(result);
        //return result;
      },
      error: function () {
        $(".toast").toast("show");
      },
    });
  });
};
```

Aquí vuelvo a llamar a mi método `rellenar` mandándole la lista que recibí y funciona. Pero solo la primera vez, donde sí recibo la información de la fila, pero la segunda vez regresa `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay algunos errores de lógica, el principal y que es el causante de comportamiento inesperado es:

Cada que ejecutas `rellenar()` llamas la función `Agregar()` y creas un nuevo "escuchador" de clics en el cuerpo de la tabla; la primera vez funciona porque solo hay una función para ejecutarse, sin embargo, cuando recargas datos y aplicas `destroy: true`, supongo que el primer escuchador pierde la referencia de `table` y por eso recibes el error.

**Posible solución:**

- Crea la variable `table` en contexto global y no la uses como parámetro para escuchar eventos
- Asigna el evento a la tabla (no al cuerpo) y fuera de la función `rellenar()`, usando la variable global para acceder a los datos

```
// Define la variable en contexto global
var table;
function rellenar(datos) {
  CalcularTotal(datos);
  // Actualiza la variable global
  table = $("#dataTable").DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    data: datos,
    columns: [
      //{ "data": "idRegistro" },
      //{ "data": "idVentas" },
      //{ "data": "idProducto" },
      { data: "producto" },
      { data: "precioUni" },
      { data: "iepsUni" },
      { data: "ivaUni" },
      { data: "cantidad" },
      { data: "estatus" },
      { data: "descuento" },
      {
        defaultContent:
          "<button type='button'id='sumar' class='plus btn btn-success'>+</button><button type='button' class='minus btn btn-warning'>-</button><button type='button' class='delete btn btn-danger'>X</button>",
      },
      //asp - action='Sumar'  asp - route - id='@item.IdProducto'
      //{ "defaultContent": "<button asp-action='EditTemporal' asp-route-id='@item.IdProducto' class='dropdown-item'>+</button><button asp-action='EditTemporal' asp-route-id='@item.IdProducto' class='dropdown-item' > -</button ><button asp-action='EliminarTempDetalle' asp-route-id='@item.IdProducto' class='dropdown-item'>Eliminar</button>"}
    ],

    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: "excel",
        text: "<i ></i>",
        className: "btn btn-success btn-sm icon-excel3",
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "th:not(:last-child)",
        },
      },
      {
        extend: "pdf",
        text: "<span ></span>",
        className: "btn btn-danger btn-sm icon-pdf3",
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "th:not(:last-child)",
        },
      },
    ],
    language: {
      lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ por página",
      zeroRecords: "Ninguna coincidencia",
      info: "Página  _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
      infoEmpty: "No hay registros disponibles",
      infoFiltered: "(_MAX_ registros)",
      sSearch: "Buscar",
      oPaginate: {
        sFirst: "Primero",
        sPrevious: "Anterior",
        sNext: "Siguiente",
        sLast: "Último",
      },
    },
  });

  // No se necesita la función Agregar
}

// Asigna el evento fuera de la función y usando la variable global
$('#dataTable').on("click", "button.plus", function () {
    var datos = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
    console.log("agregar");
    console.log(datos);
    //$('#IdProductoDetalle').val(datos['idProducto']);

    //$('#CantidadDetalle').val(1);
    //articular();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/veVentas/Sumar",
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        idProducto: datos["idProducto"],
      },
      traditional: true,
      success: function (result) {
        console.log("result");
        console.log(result);
        console.log("result 0");
        console.log(result[0]);

        rellenar(result);
        //return result;
      },
      error: function () {
        $(".toast").toast("show");
      },
    });
});
```

Se asigna el evento a la tabla y no al cuerpo (`tbody`) porque podría no existir, ya sea porque no lo incluiste en el código HTML o porque al usar `destroy: true` hay la posibilidad de que se elimine y se vuelve a crear, desconozco cómo funciona esta parte.

No importa en qué momento agregues filas, la función se va a ejecutar solo cuando se haga clic en un botón con clase `plus` y siempre va a acceder a los datos que tenga la variable global `table`.

Seguramente hay mejores formas de manejar *DataTable*, por ejemplo, simplemente cargar un nuevo conjunto de datos, pero tu código no está planteado para ese escenario.